# Se puede instalar JVM sin JRE

Tags: java

soy nuevo en esto de java y estoy tratando de entender las diferencias entre JVM y JRE.
Entiendo que la JVM es parte de JRE.
Mi duda es si: ¿las aplicaciones JAVA pueden correr en un equipo que tenga solo JVM y NO JRE?
¿En que caso es imprescindible tener JRE para correr una aplicación JAVA?

Desde ya muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Creo que [aquí está claramente explicada la diferencia](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-jdk-jre-jvm/). Como respuesta corta: Sí, es imprescindible tener JRE para ejecutar una aplicación. Nunca me había planteado si era posible tener JVM sin JRE instalado, de ser posible, JVM no bastaría para ejecutar un programa. La única posibilidad que se menciona es la de [*Self-Contained Application Packaging*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html), que no es otra cosa que una especie de instalación *mínima*  de JRE en la máquina.

Comment: En la documentación oficial se dice esto de forma explícita: [**4.3.1 No JRE:** *If the user does not have the JRE installed, then **the application cannot start**.*  **4.3.1.1 Standalone Launch:** *The main application JAR file includes a launcher program, which is used to detect the JRE. **If the JRE is not found, then a dialog box is shown that explains where to get the JRE**.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/deploy_user_experience.html#sthref34)